# How to prevent Mathematica from giving inexact answers

Tags: machine-precision, precision-and-accuracy

Upon doing a simple subtraction `13.725 - 13.5` both Mathematica 11.3 and 12.0 beta version are giving me `0.22499999999999964` although both display the answer as `0.225`. Is there a way to yield the answer in exact form. For now I can only use `SetPrecision` to address the issue:

`SameQ[0.22499999999999964, 0.225] && Equal[0.22499999999999964, 0.225]`

`(*False*)`

`SameQ[SetPrecision[0.22499999999999964, 4], 0.225] && Equal[SetPrecision[0.22499999999999964, 4], 0.225]`

`(*True*)`

I have a code with some degree of complexity and I am going to simplify the problem a bit here. lets say i have two points with (x,y,z) coordinates and i want to say that the translation of a point by a vector: `{13.725, 0.8397114317029974, 0.46748599816306713} - {13.50, 0., 0.} = {0.22499999999999964, 0.8397114317029974, 0.46748599816306713}` is equal to a point 'b' `{0.225, 0.8397114317029974, 0.46748599816306713}`. How can this be done easily?

Comment: tried `Rationalize`?

Comment: "how to prevent *Mathematica* from giving inexact answers" - cheeky answer: don't start with inexact input in the first place

Comment: @kglr it works in simple case. but I have a code with some degree of complexity. I am going to simplify the problem a bit. lets say i have two points with (x,y,z) coordinates and i want to say that the translation of a point by a vector {13.725, 0.8397114317029974, 0.46748599816306713} - {13.50, 0., 0.} = `{0.22499999999999964, 0.8397114317029974, 0.46748599816306713}` is equal to a point 'b' `{0.225, 0.8397114317029974, 0.46748599816306713}`

Comment: @J.M.isslightlypensive hahaha .. good to see you back !

Comment: Ali, I meant try using  `Rationalize` on inputs.

Comment: What you want can be effected for print purposes, but numerically it is basically not possible. Such are the vagaries of going from decimal to binary and back to decimal, all in finite precision.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau i understand what you are saying but on a simple calculator when i do 13.725 - 13.50 I get 0.225 .. But not in Mathematica. I think i have a misunderstanding about how inexact numbers work in computer and a hand held calculator

Comment: @kglr I think this works N@Rationalize[inputA - translationVector] == inputB

Comment: You might also try `And @@ PossibleZeroQ[inputA - translationVector - inputB]` instead of trying to compare the translated A to point B.

Comment: I believe some calculators use BCD (binary coded decimal). A calculator that uses BCD arithmetic will not have decimal-to-binary-to-decimal conversion issues. See for example [this page](https://www.quora.com/How-much-is-Binary-Coded-Decimal-BCD-used-these-days-and-how-important-is-it-where-it-is-used)

Comment: This might help: http://support.wolfram.com/kb/42750 (with understanding the problem moreso than immediately fixing it)

Answer (score 1):

With the numbers in your example, equality testing with [`Equal`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal.html) (i.e. `==`) already works:

```
pointA = {13.725, 0.8397114317029974, 0.46748599816306713};
transVec = {13.50, 0., 0.};
pointB = {0.225, 0.8397114317029974, 0.46748599816306713};

pointA - transVec == pointB
(* True *)
```

This is because [`Equal`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal.html) considers approximate numbers with machine precision equal "if they differ in at most their last seven binary digits (roughly their last two decimal digits)" (from the Details section of its docs).

However, that threshold may not be appropriate for you, so you can use other methods. For instance, evaluate the distance between the two points (e.g. with [`Norm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Norm.html)) and check whether it is less than an appropriate threshold:

```
Norm[(pointA - transVec) - pointB] < 10 $MachineEpsilon
(* True *)
```

Note, however, that the above will remain unevaluated if its truth value cannot be decided. For instance, imagine that, contrary to your expectation, a symbol does *not* have a numerical value (here I am using `pointC` without having assigned it a value):

```
Norm[(pointA - transVec) - pointC] < 10 $MachineEpsilon
```

> Sqrt[Abs[0.22499999999999964 - pointC]^2 + 
>      Abs[0.46748599816306713 - pointC]^2 + 
>          Abs[0.8397114317029974 - pointC]^2] < 2.220446049250313*^-15

That may or may not be desirable (that's your design decision); if you want to avoid it, though, you can wrap the inequality in [`TrueQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrueQ.html):

```
TrueQ[Norm[(pointA - transVec) - pointC] < 10 $MachineEpsilon]
(* False *)
```